# Is it encouraged or discouraged to use interfaces simply to enforce consistency?

Tags: object-oriented

What do you think about using interfaces just for the sake of enforcing certain naming and patterns across your team? Other than that, it doesn't hold any practical value programmatically.

I'm on the fence on this one because I tend to minimize abstraction whenever possible, but this seems a bit unnecessary. However, it does have some value when it comes to creating variations of certain classes which aren't necessarily related.

Comment: If you are talking about Java interfaces are not just for enforcing naming patterns. They can hold default methods, get passed as functional interfaces etc.

Comment: How would using interfaces enforce certain naming and (sic) patterns?

Answer (score 4):

> What do you guys think about using interfaces just for

Adding a language element to a program makes it more complex. What we should strive for is the *least* complex program to fulfill all the requirements. Because that should be the easiest to write, to understand, modify, bugfix and generally speaking "produce and maintain".

So if I can go and *remove* your language element (interface in this case, but the same goes for base classes or other elements) by replacing it by specific instances where needed and your program still works the same, then it should never have been in there in the first place. It was not needed, it just added unnecessary complexity. If I cannot remove it because the program won't work with a replacement (say you inject different implementations for your interface on testing) then it is a *necessary* complexity and should stay.

If you want to have your classes follow a naming guideline, use a linter or equivalent tool. Not only does it make your program less complex, it is also the right place to put in custom messages why this is necessary. A compiler message will only tell you *that* something is wrong, a linter with custom messages can tell you *why* you need to do it differently in your context.

Comment: Code reviews work even better.